# Kubernetes-dashboard empty : every resources are forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-dashboard

It seems I have a very common problem but I cannot figure it out.

On a new kubernetes cluster (v1.17) I'm trying to install Kubernetes-dashboard.

For this I followed the official steps, starting by installing the dashboard :

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc5/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Then I created the ServiceAccount

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

And the ClusterRoleBinding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Everything is running smoothly and all the objets get created (I can get them and everything looks alright)

After running `kubectl proxy` the dashboard is accessible at this URL :

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

Then I enter the token I got with this command :

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | grep admin-user-token | awk '{print $1}')
```

I can login, but the dashboard is empty. The notifications panel is full of

> [OBJECT] is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:admin-user" cannot list resource "[OBJECT]" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "default"

*Replace [OBJECT] with every kubernetes object and you have a good overview of my notifications panel ;)*

The admin-user has obviously not enough rights to access the objects.

**Questions**

- Did I miss something ?
- How can I debug this situation ?

Thank you for your help !

**Edit:** That was an outage from my cloud provider. I don't know what happened nor how they solved it but they did something and everything is working now.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. This question looks interesting to me. I'll try to investigate and let you know. In case you would resolve the issue faster, please let me know as well

Comment: I tried reproducing it on GKE, hoewver without success. It works as charm on GKE. Are you using standalone installation (kubeadm, etc)? What are server/client versions? By the way, you can explore  `kubectl auth can-i  --namespace=default --as admin-user  --list` output in order to get more insights on

Comment: Thank you for your investigation. I'm not the one who installed kubernetes, it's a solution from a cloud provider (OVH). The client version is 1.17.2 and the server version is 1.17.0. I'm running the auth command but I don't fully understand the output. I'll dig into that to understand if my permissions are sufficient.

Comment: Okay, that was an outage from the cloud provider. I ran into another problem with PVC, they solved it and tadaa the dashboard is working just fine with no modifications.

Comment: Community will appreciate if you paste that info as an accepted answer, so the question won't be orphaned one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, that was an outage from the cloud provider. I ran into another problem with PVC, they solved it and tadaa the dashboard is working just fine with no modifications.

Answer (score 1):

role binding give this error?

The ClusterRoleBinding "kubernetes-dashboard" is invalid: roleRef: Invalid value: rbac.RoleRef{APIGroup:"rbac.authorization.k8s.io", Kind:"ClusterRole", Name:"cluster-admin"}: cannot change roleRef